# Disabling CheckedTextView

Tags: android, android-layout, checkedtextview

I use CheckedTextView. I am Disabling it using the method "setEnabled(false)" . If I do so, only the colour of the text changes to grey, but its still checkable. How to disable CheckedTextview? Even I tried with setClickable(false), even that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

setFocusable, setFocusableInTouchMode to false.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for

> isSelected()

method. It will surely solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `chkTextView.setEnabled(false);` for disable click on checkbox it works for me.